# how to unreserve ports in windows

Tags: windows, sharepoint, port

I am using **SharePoint framework webpart** and the default port for workbench is 4321, for another webpart developing the port is reserved and the workbench page is cant reach, I changed the port to 4322 for example, but how we can unreserved the default port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port for SPFX WebPart is denified in config->serve.json, you can change to the default port there:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true,
  "initialPage": "https://localhost:5432/workbench",
  "api": {
    "port": 5432,
    "entryPath": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer, but i want to use 5432  again, i dont want to change the port, how i can?

Comment: It's necessary to change the port in serve.json, the port is maintained in this file.

Comment: sorry but i neede to use 5432 again, how is it possible? its my question

Comment: One SPFX Solution can only host in a unique port, no matter which port you want to use, you need to modify serve.json.